# Exercise 23 of Rudin chapter 8

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, curves, complex-integration

Let $\gamma$ be a continuously differentiable closed curve in the complex plane with parameter interval $[a,b]$, and assume that $\gamma (t) \ne 0$ for all $ t \in [a,b]$. Define the index of $\gamma$ to be
$$\text{Ind} (\gamma) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma (t)} dt$$

Prove that this is always an integer.

In the hint it's mentioned there is a function $\phi$ on $[a,b]$ with $\phi ' =\frac{\gamma'}{\gamma}$ and $\phi(a)=0$.

I can understand that the primitive of $\frac{\gamma'}{\gamma}$ exists since it is continuous and integrable but cannot understand why $\phi(a)=0$ which plays a vital role in the proof.

Comment: Yes, and also I mentioned $\gamma 0=1$. I will edit it.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1197670/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map
\begin{align}
\varphi(t)=\exp\Big(\int^t_a \frac{\gamma'(s)}{\gamma(s)}\,ds\Big),
\qquad t\in[a,b].
\end{align}
We will show that $\phi(b)=1$. The fundamental theorem of calculus
implies that
\begin{align}
\varphi'(t)=\frac{\varphi(t)\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)},
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\Big( \frac{\varphi}{\gamma}\Big)=\frac{(\gamma-z)\varphi'-\varphi\gamma'}{(\gamma)^2}=\frac{\varphi\gamma'-\varphi\gamma'}{(\gamma)^2}=0
\end{align}
Thus, $\frac{\phi}{\gamma}$ is constant in $[a,b]$. In particular,
\begin{align}
\frac{\varphi(b)}{\gamma(b)}=\frac{\varphi(a)}{\gamma(a)}=
\frac{1}{\gamma(b)}
\end{align}
since $\varphi(a)=1$ and $\gamma(b)=\gamma(a)$. Consequently,
$\varphi(b)=1$. From this it must be that $$\int^b_a\frac{\gamma'}{\gamma}=2\pi in$$ for some integer $n$ (recall that $e^z=1$ iff $z\in 2\pi i\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Very nice solution! Thank you so much.