# Some questions on index and single-valued property of Riemann-Hilbert Problems

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{C} $ be bounded and simply connected domain, $\Gamma := \partial D \in C^2 $,  $ g \in C^{0,\alpha}(\Gamma) $ be a complex-valued and nowhere vanishing function defined on the contour $\Gamma$ . The index of $g$  is defined by
$$
\text{ind} \ g := \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\Gamma} d \text{arg} g. 
$$
**Question1:**
Why it must be a integer?

**My Thoughts:** Since i think $g(z)$ may not go around the circle `by interger times when $z$  go around the $\Gamma $.

Let $\text{ind} g = \kappa $. Choose a point $a \in D $, define $G \in C^{0,\alpha}(\Gamma) $ by
$$
G(z) := (z-a)^{-\kappa} g(z), \quad z \in \Gamma.
$$
It has index $\text{ind} \ G = 0 $.

**Question2:** Why any branch of the logarithm can give a single-valued function $ \ln G \in C^{0,\alpha}(\Gamma) $?

**My Thoughts:** I suspect the possibility that the $G$ may turn counter-clockwise for some circles and then go back to the origin? This would destroy the single-valued property of some branch of logarithm?

Note: The latter question is one step in [Kress, Linear integral equations, P117].

Comment: For the first question compare e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1197670/42969

Comment: @Martin R It is helpful. The latter?