Why is the winding number line integral an integer?
The winding number around the origin of a closed curve $C\subseteq  \mathbb{R}^{2}$ with parameter representation $t\mapsto (x(t),y(t)$ where $x,y:\left[ 0,1 \right]\to \mathbb{R}$ are continuously differentiable functions satisfying $x(0)=x(1)$ and $y(0)=y(1)$ can be defined as $w(C,0):=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(t)y'(t)-y(t)x'(t)}{x^{2}(t)+y^{2}(t)}dt$. Is there a direct simple but rigorous analytical/computational way (not using the tools covering/covering map from topology) to show that this is always an integer?

See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1197670/42969 and the linked questions.

See it as a complex integral and exponentiate it.

It looks like you confuse the winding number
$$
\frac1{2\pi}\int_C\frac{x\,dy-y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}
$$
from real analysis with that from complex analysis:
$$
\frac1{2\pi\color{red}i}\int_C\frac{dz}{z-a}\,.
$$
That the former is an integer can be seen by direct computation (parametrize the circle $C$ with polar coordinates). That the latter is an integer follows from the fact that the antiderivative of the integrand is $\log(z-a)$ which has a branch cut at which it jumps by $2\pi i\,.$
In the real analysis case the "antiderivative" of the one-form that we integrate is
$$
\phi(x,y)={\rm sign}( y)\,\arccos\Big(\textstyle\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\Big)\,,
$$
or simply $\phi(r,\theta)=\theta$ in polar coordinates. This jumps by
$2\pi$ at its "branch cut". See this post for elaborations.
Edit: After a comment made by Martin R I'd like to highlight a bit that the link between the two integrals is much closer than I originally thought.

In complex analysis we learn to integrate over a circle $C$ as follows:
$$
\gamma:t\mapsto r\,e^{2\pi i t}=z(t)=x(t)+i\,y(t)\,.
$$
Then, since $dz=2\pi i\, r\,e^{2\pi i t}\,dt $ and $1/z=e^{-2\pi i t}/r\,,$
$$
\int_C\frac{dz}z=2\pi i\int_0^1\,dt=2\pi i\,.
$$
If we instead go a slightly harder route we write
$dz=(\dot x+i\dot y)\,dt$ and $1/z=\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}$ and get
\begin{align}
\int_C\frac{dz}z&=\int_0^1\frac{(x-iy)(\dot x+i\dot y)}{x^2+y^2}\,dt=\int_0^1\frac{x\dot x+y\dot y}{x^2+y^2}\,dt+i\int_0^1\frac{x\dot y-y\,\dot x}{x^2+y^2}\,dt
\end{align}
The second integral is nothing else than the one of the real one-form
$\omega=\frac{x\,dy-y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}$ and the first integral is zero
because on the circle $x^2+y^2$ is constant and the numerator
is the $t$-derivative of this.


$C$ is an arbitrary closed curve, not necessariliy a circle.

@MartinR sure. I cheated a bit. :) To see that it holds for arbitrary closed curves one must show that they can be deformed into the circle without changing the integral. This is equivalent to showing that when the curve does not wind around the singularity the integral is zero. In the real analysis case this boils down to showing (Poincare lemma) that the $1$-form we integrate is exact when we take out a branch cut. In the complex case the idea is the same: $\log$ doesn't jump when we don't wind around the singularity.

But what “confusion” are you talking about? If you parameterize $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_C \frac{dz}{z}$ with $\gamma(t) = x(t) +i y(t)$ then you get $\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(t)y'(t)-y(t)x'(t)}{x^{2}(t)+y^{2}(t)}dt$ which (apart from an errornous factor $i$) is what OP wrote. So that are the same winding numbers, and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1197670/42969 (from my above comment) provides a simple proof that this is an integer. I am tempted to close this as a duplicate.

@MartinR all right. I agree it is pretty much a duplicate and you nicely highlighted the link between the two integrals. Nonetheless I find the differences between them not uninteresting. The real one-form is then the sister of the complex one form $i\frac{dz}z$ and $\arccos$ the brother of $\log,.$

I have removed this errornous factor i.

Why not use Green's Theorem instead of complex analysis?

@KurtG This 1-form in the real integral is closed but not exact: it does not have an antiderivative in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\left{ 0 \right}$, otherwise this integral over a closed curve would vanish.

@UdoZerwas I know. What I meant in that comment above was that we take closed curves that do not wind around zero. They stay in a simply connected region $\mathbb C$ minus the branch cut where the form is closed and exact.
